# CA1303 warning - Method passes a literal string as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a "PageNotFound"-view in the shared views folder, and wherever I would use `return NotFound();` after a trip to the database, I'm doing this instead:

```
if (something == null)
{
    return View("PageNotFound", 
                new PageNotFoundViewModel { Message = "Something does not exist." });
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class PageNotFoundViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Is it concidered bad practice?

VS is warning me that

> Method 'Task SomeController.Details(int? id)' passes a literal string as parameter 'value' of a call to 'void PageNotFoundViewModel.Message.set'. Retrieve the following string(s) from a resource table instead: "Something does not exist.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1303?view=vs-2019

*This is just a warning*

> Cause
>
> A method passes a string literal as a parameter to a .NET constructor
>   or method and that string should be localizable.
>
> This warning is raised when a literal string is passed as a value to a
>   parameter or property and one or more of the following cases is true:
>
> ```
> The LocalizableAttribute attribute of the parameter or property is set to true.
>
> The parameter or property name contains "Text", "Message", or "Caption".
>
> The name of the string parameter that is passed to a Console.Write or Console.WriteLine method is either "value" or "format".
> ```
>
> By default, this rule analyzes the entire codebase, but this is
>   configurable.

AFAIK This is just a localization warning when you are going to support multiple languages you should comply to this rule to ease the selection of the selected culture for the user